# Is there a comprehensive course on Google Earth Engine for beginners?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am unable to find any courses online specifically for use of Google Earth Engine for those adept with other GIS software like Esri ArcGIS or QGIS.

For example, there is an excellent course for ArcGIS by UC Davis on coursera ([UC Davis course on GIS in ArcGIS](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/gis)).

Comment: Did you google it? GEE provides a list of tutorials for different aspects of GEE: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the GEE documentation but because it is recent, I don't think that there is any course exist on the Internet. But you can see the video for intro level analysis. Link is given below.
https://www.youtube.com/user/TheJosiahcorona